# Select multiple DIVs based in ID , excluding mutiple child DIVs

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need help selecting the following DIVs based on IDs but excluding some of the children DIVs in two different types of pages using a single style.css file:

PAGE1:

```
...
<div id="main">
    <div id="post"> selected </div>
</div>
...
```

PAGE2:

```
...
<div id="main">
    <div id="maincontent"> selected </div>
    <div id="singlepost">
        <div id="post"> selected </div>
        <div id="comments"> excluded </div>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar"> excluded </div>
</div>
....
```

I have tried with:

```
#main > :not(#sidebar), #singlepost > :not(#comments) a {
        color: rgb(88, 134, 76) !important;
}
```

(!important overrides some inline CSS I cannot change)

The result is bad because Chrome only recognizes `#main > :not(#sidebar),` and ignores `#singlepost > :not(#comments) a`, thus turning all text into this color, not just links, and only excluding `<div id="sidebar">`, not `<div id="comments?>`.

I also tried:

```
#singlepost > :not(#comments) a {
        color: rgb(88, 134, 76) !important;
}

#main > :not(#sidebar) a {
        color: rgb(88, 134, 76) !important;
}
```

Now everything works as intended but `<div id="comments">` is not excluded.

Please help,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

Try to overwrite your style for `#comments` using `!important` for a certain property.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class name:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="maincontent" class="selected"> selected </div>
    <div id="singlepost" class="selected">
        <div id="post" class="selected-items"> selected </div>
        <div id="comments" class="notSeleted-item"> excluded </div>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar" class="notSelected"> excluded </div>
</div>
```

you would use the class, like this:

```
.selected {/*your style*/}
.selected-item a{/*your style*/}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do

```
#maincontent, #post {
  color: rgb(88, 134, 76);
}
```

[example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tqAsC)

Since you're using ids.

Another way would be to create a class for them. [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lojAw)